# NULL a Parameter based on another Parameter's selection

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've got a parameter called @Dummy that sets the date parameters to NULL if the selection is 2 (or the second option) in @Dummy. Else it inserts a date into my two date parameters.

What I want to do is add another option where it inserts today's date into my two date parameters AND sets the next parameter (@ProgressCode) to NULL.

```
IF @Dummy=2 
SELECT NULL as Date 
ELSE 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103) as Date
```

This bit of code works OK so far for me but I have no idea to go about setting @ProgressCode to NULL. I don't think AND will work, nor SELECT NULL :S

Answer (score 0):

Use `begin` and `end` to place multiple statements after the `else`:

```
ELSE IF @Dummy = 3
    BEGIN
    SET @DatePar = getdate()
    SET @ProgressCode = null
    END
```

Of course, you can also set multiple variables with a single `select`:

```
ELSE IF @Dummy = 3
    SELECT  @DatePar = getdate()
    ,       @ProgressCode = null
```